# sapui5:How to display base64 image in Rich text editor?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I created an img element string with base64 source. when tried to display it in sap.ui.richtexteditor.RichTextEditor, I got nothing. How to display it? see my code.

```
// controller
var template = {};
var image ="<img src="data:image/bmp;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRg...">";
template.body = image;
var oViewModel = new JSONModel(template);
this.getView().setModel(oViewModel, "template");
//view
<rte:RichTextEditor id="rte" value="{template>/body}" editorType="TinyMCE4" customToolbar="true" showGroupFont="true" showGroupInsert="true"
showGroupLink="true" height="360px"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

why dont use the [Image Control](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Image)?

`<Image src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoA...........=='/>`

Comment: data in rich text editor should be a html string. <Image/> is a sapui5 element, not html.